# Cannot connect to SQL Server via TCP/IP from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Software:

- Windows 2012 server R2
- SQL Server express (64 bit), installed by choosing all defaults
- SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, installed on the same machine

When I connect from SQL Server Management Studio to SQL Server, it works fine as long as I have "Network protocol" on the connection tab set to `<default>`.

When I set the protocol to TCP/IP, the connection fails:

> A network related error ... The server was not found or was not accessible...

I checked with the SQL Server Configuration Manager that TCP/IP is enabled on the server as well as on the client. I can't find help from Google.

One observation: after the installation, the SQL Server Configuration Manager would not come up (Configuration Manager Cannot Connect To WMI Provider). I followed this advise (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igl-CB0qP_c) and got it to work.

Comment: Check your firewall has port 1433 open on the SQL Server

Comment: I have turned the firewall off. Error still persists.

Comment: You have to enable the protocol on Sql Server too.

Comment: As I mentioned in the text: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to post a comment due to reputation score so I had to post an answer.

Some things to try/check:

Start the SQL Browser Service if it is not running

Check the SQL Error Log to ensure it is running on port 1433

Are you connecting to servername\SQLEXPRESS in the connection dialog

Try telnet to connect `telnet servername port`

if it goes to a blank screen instead of giving you a failure to connect then it is communicating. Ctrl + ] to cancel the connection.

Comment: Thanks. `telnet <servername> 1433` gives an empty screen. Using port number 1434 gives an error message ("Could not open..."). That means the port is open.